# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ^: 'int' and 'str'

Tags: python

```
a = 0b11101110

print a ^ 0b1111
print bin(238) ^ 0b1111
```

If trying to flip the second half of a, the first approach works but the second throws:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ^: 'str' and 'int'

I suppose this means that going through bin() makes

```
0b11101110
```

into a string. How would I get the second approach to work? As in how could I convert 238 into base 2 in order to use the XOR (or even the & or |) operator?

Comment: What have you tried to achieve your wanted results? What has your research concerning your problem shown? Can you provide code of your tries? [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How much research effort is expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) might be helpful to improve your question.

Comment: You don't need to convert 238 to binary to do `^`. Use it as it is `238 ^ 0b1111`

Comment: Numbers **do not have** "a base", or "digits". Those are **only** properties of *how the number is written out*, i.e. a *string representation of* the number. `^` operates on the bits of an integer. Integers *do* have bits.

Answer (score 0):

For Decimal use:

```
238 ^ 0b1111
```

Ans: 225

For Binary result:

```
bin(238 ^ 0b1111)
```

Ans:0b11100001